# Close form of a series

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

Does the following series have a close form?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{\left(1-q^n\right)^3}$$
The final result may be related with combinations of Jacobi theta function, Dedekind function $\eta(\tau)$ and Eisenstein series.

This kind of series appear when we compute the following kind of integral:
$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1 d\mathfrak{a}_1\int_0^1 d\mathfrak{a}_2\wp\left(\mathfrak{a}_1-\mathfrak{a}_2+\frac{\tau}{2}|\tau\right)\wp\left(2\mathfrak{a}_1+\mathfrak{a}_2+\frac{\tau}{2}|\tau\right)\wp\left(2\mathfrak{a}_2+\mathfrak{a}_1+\frac{\tau}{2}|\tau\right)$
where the Weierstrass p function $\wp(z|\tau)$ is defined by:
$$ \wp(z|\tau) = \ \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{(m,n) \ne (0,0)} \left[\frac{1}{(z - m - n \tau)^2} - \frac{1}{(m + n \tau)^2}\right] $$
By using its Fourier expansion
$$\ 4\pi^2 \mathbb{E}_2(\tau) - 2 \pi^2 i \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\frac{n q^{- \frac{n}{2}}}{\sin n \pi \tau}e^{2\pi i nz}$$
we can transform this integral into:
$$\mathcal{I}=64\pi^6\mathbb{E}_2(\tau)^3-128\pi^6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{\left(1-q^n\right)^3}$$
where $\mathbb{E}_2(\tau)$ represents the Eisenstein Series.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{3n}}{\left(1-q^{2n}\right)^3}=\sum_{m\ge 1} \sum_{d|m,\ 2\ \nmid\ d}(m/d)^3 \frac{d^2-1}8 q^m$ which is mostly $E_4(q)-2E_4(q)- c(qE_2'(q))'-8c(2q (2qE_2'(2q))')$

Comment: Yes, I know that $\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^2 \mathbb{E}_2(q)$ would produce $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{n}\left(1+q^{n}\right)}{\left(1-q^n\right)^3}$, or, if you turn $q\to q^2$ you would get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{2n}\left(1+q^{2n}\right)}{\left(1-q^{2n}\right)^3}$, but I still have no idea how to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{3n}}{\left(1-q^{2n}\right)^3}$

Comment: I have tried something like $-a \frac{d}{d q}\left(q \frac{d \text{E}_2(q)}{d q}\right)+2 b q \frac{d }{d q}\left(2 q \frac{d\text{E}_2(2 q)}{d q}\right)+\text{E}_4(q)$ in Mathematica which is far from correct

Comment: Ah, I know what you mean, If I try the following in Mathematica:$$-\frac{1}{4}\left.\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^2\mathbb{E}_2(q)\right|_{q\to q^2}+\frac{1}{16}\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^2\mathbb{E}_2(q)-\frac{3}{8}\mathbb{E}_4(q)+\frac{3}{8}\mathbb{E}_4(q^2)$$ it does produce:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3 q^{3 n}}{\left(1-q^{2 n}\right)^3}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3q^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{\left(1-q^n\right)^3}=-\frac{1}{4}\left(2 \mathbb{E}_2(\tau)^3-30\mathbb{E}_2(\tau)\mathbb{E}_4(\tau)+70\mathbb{E}_6(\tau)\right)+\frac{1}{16}\left(2 \mathbb{E}_2\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)^3-30\mathbb{E}_2\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)\mathbb{E}_4\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)+70\mathbb{E}_6\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)\right)\notag\\
-\frac{3}{8}\mathbb{E}_4\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{8}\mathbb{E}_4\left(\tau\right)$$